# cmake ignoring include directory when cross compiling

Tags: linux, cmake

I am perplexed and would like your help.

I am cross compiling a project that requires `ifaddrs.h`, but no matter how I try to specify the location of the file, it never finds it.  It is located at `/usr/include/ifaddrs.h` and I have used the code below to try to point to it.  (Granted this is the host system's file, but that should not matter in this context.  I have also put the file in the target systems include directory: `/tmp/toolchain/include` with no different results).  And the `message` call does print `/usr/include`

If, however, I put the file in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include` 
it is found.  It is there, I can see it -- why not cmake?

```
FIND_FILE( IFADDRS ifaddrs.h PATH /usr/include )
get_filename_component(if_path ${IFADDRS} PATH)
message( "IFADDRS = " ${if_path} )
include_directories( ${if_path} )
include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include )
```

Changing the code above to this:

```
include_directories( BEFORE SYSTEM /usr/include )
```

and running `make VERBOSE=1` gives this:

```
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cpcommon_lib.dir/eui48.c.o
/tmp/toolchain/arm-linux-uclibc/bin/gcc  -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -I/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/../include -I/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/../../pjproject/pjlib-util/include -I/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/../../pjproject/pjlib/include -I/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/../../pjproject/pjnath/include -I/usr/include/w32api -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/X11 -I/usr/pkg/include -I/opt/csw/include -I/opt/include -I/usr/openwin/include -I/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/../../cjson    -o CMakeFiles/cpcommon_lib.dir/eui48.c.o   -c /home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/eui48.c
In file included from /home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/eui48.c:26:
/home/bp/MySnapCam/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src/impl/eui48_unix.c:14:21: ifaddrs.h: No such file or directory
```

There is no `/usr/include/` in the include paths.  It is also not in the flags.make files either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which directory is your `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`?  I ask because you say that giving the path relative to that works.  Also, what does `${if_path}` return?

Comment: Thank you for the reply -- ${IFADDRS} = /usr/include/ifaddrs.h  and ${if_path} = /usr/include.  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} = /home/bp/projects/Communication/trunk/cpcommon/src   FWIW, if I set_source_files_properties( eui48.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-I/usr/include" )
 it is found, but that causes other problems when it gets searched first.  Can I, perhaps, append the file property, so it gets searched last?

Comment: Try running `make VERBOSE=1` and don't set `set_source_files_properties`.  Take a look at include directories and see if `/usr/include` is being added or not. This will tell us if the error is with CMake or something else. Before you do this, clean out `CMakeCache` and re-run `cmake` so that you are starting from scratch.

Comment: I edited the question above -- there wasn't enough space in a comment.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's a last-ditch effort.  `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is designed to take more than one path at a time.  It's *possible* that if you are calling it multiple times, each call overwrites the previous.  Try calling it only once and see what happens: `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${if_path} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)`